# Unhide <img> on :hover

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have an image hidden by default and unhide it on `:hover`? I tried using the visibility property, but invisible elements can't be hovered on.

Comment: Have you tried `display: none` css property?

Comment: $("#imageId").css("display", "block");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly you can't mouseover/hover a hidden image that is, its not possible with `visibility:hidden;` or `display:none;`, but you can have some tricks to do that.

**using css**

apply `opacity: 0;` to the image and :hover change `opacity:1;`

**using js**

create a parent `<div>` to the image and `mouseover` to that `div` apply `display:block;` to image.

Working Fiddle **[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/randeep161/NF9XZ/)**

Answer (score 4):

If you use display or visibility, the element is not there so you can't hover over it. Try it with  `opacity:0;` . You can do it with css:

```
.img { opacity:0; }
.img:hover { opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize that you specifically asked about jquery, but it is possible to do what you're asking just with css, though you may have to use opacity:0 rather than display:none to hide the image.

You can use a css hover event. Start by applying a class to your image:

```
<img src="theimage.jpg" class="hidden-image"/>
```

In your css, you can then use the class and a css hover event to show the image when the cursor is over the image:

```
.hidden-image {
   opacity: 0;
}

.hidden-image:hover {
   opacity:1;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZd7J/

Comment: thanks, this solutions with changing opacity helped me!